# Why can not I place my custom textbox inside a panel or groupBox?

Tags: c#, winforms, custom-controls, panel, groupbox

I have a custom TextBox control defined as follows:

```
class PHTextBox : System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
{
    System.Drawing.Color DefaultColor;
    public string PlaceHolderText { get; set; }

    public PHTextBox(string placeholdertext)
    {
        // get default color of text
        DefaultColor = this.ForeColor;
        // Add event handler for when the control gets focus
        this.GotFocus += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
        {
            this.Text = String.Empty;
            this.ForeColor = DefaultColor;
        };

        // add event handling when focus is lost
        this.LostFocus += (Object sender, EventArgs e) => {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Text) || this.Text == PlaceHolderText)
            {
                this.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Gray;
                this.Text = PlaceHolderText;
            }
            else
            {
                this.ForeColor = DefaultColor;
            }
        };

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(placeholdertext))
        {
            // change style   
            this.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Gray;

            // Add text
            PlaceHolderText = placeholdertext;
            this.Text = placeholdertext;
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to add a custom textBox in the following way to a Panel:

```
this.tbNombresClienteConfirmarPago = new PHTextBox("Your name");
this.tbNombresClienteConfirmarPago.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0,0);//(644, 485);
this.tbNombresClienteConfirmarPago.Name = "tbNombresClienteConfirmarPago";
this.tbNombresClienteConfirmarPago.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(203, 20);
this.tbNombresClienteConfirmarPago.TabIndex = 7;
this.tbNombresClienteConfirmarPago.MaxLength = 50;
this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.tbNombresClienteConfirmarPago);
```

But it does not work.

I add a textBox or a button that belong to Windows Forms and they are added correctly to the Panel without problems.

Any comment is welcomed.

Upgrade:

When I wanted to say that 'It doesn't work' I was referring to the fact that the object is not displayed inside the Panel.

A PHTextBox is displayed correctly within the form.

Comment: What does *it does not work* mean, here? It's not added to the Panel? It doesn't work as expected? What was expected to happen?  Btw, add an empty constructor to the class: `public PHTextBox() {  }`.

Comment: I mean, that is not visualized.

Comment: In the form PHTextBox is displayed without problems .

Comment: Code works as posted.  It shows up inside a panel, no problem.

Comment: Do you have other controls inside that Panel?

Comment: I have added a button to determine if the same thing happens, and the button appears without problems. I suspect that something else must have the PHTextBox class so that it can be added to a panel.